# iotedge as transparent gateway on Azure Windows virtual machine - External Switch

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-iot-edge

I'm building an azure iot-edge solution on a windows 10 Azure VM. The solution require to build iotedge as a transparent gateway in order to send data from Kepware to it.
To do that reading the Microsoft documentation I see that I require to build an external virtual switch in order to configure the gateway device as a server so that downstream devices can connect to it securely. I have some problem doing that, so that looking at the documentation I read here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/nested-virtualization?view=iotedge-2020-11 that Azure VM does not support external switches.

Do you have some workaround to allow me to send data from kepware to iotedge modules?
In case I misread something please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual machine can support external switch in hyper -V manager try to connect your virtual machine via RDP in your remote desktop.

You can Enable Hyper-V using ***powershell*** or ***Deployment Imaging Servicing and Management tool (DISM***) or in **Apps and Features** setting please refer this **[MsDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)**

***In server manager -> Tools -> Hyper-V manager***
[image]

In Hyper-V management console You can find ***virtual switch manager*** like below

[image]

You can establish three switches in a virtual switch, and the external switch will enable connectivity to the outside network and bind to the physical adapter so the virtual machine can access the physical network.

If you are going to access virtual machine from client or anything from out, you need to external switches is required and create virtual switch.
[image]

Click external network and select ethernet adapter and allow management operating system to network adaptor, apply and configure like below.

[image]

Comment: I did that part, but then when I deployed the iotedge module (Deploy-EflowVm -vSwitchType "External" -vSwitchName "EFLOW-Ext") using that external switch it did not find any ip  So I went into docs and found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/nested-virtualization?view=iotedge-2020-11 (last paragraph in purple) that azure vm external switch may not be compatible. Do you have any experience on that?

Comment: yes you are right Azure VMs do not support using an external virtual switch.